# How to Change the number of arguments to pass values to function as required by the user in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, parameter-passing

```
def function(arg1,arg2,arg3,....):

    do...something

arg1 = 2

arg2 = 3

function(arg1,arg2,arg3,....)
```

The number of arguments can change depending upon the user input.It can be 2 or 3 or 10 or 15 or anything.

I need to able to pass as many arguments as needed not more or less.
The statement should be adaptable.

Comment: Look at [Understanding kwargs in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python).

Comment: Easily!! Use function(*arg)
then use all of your arguments.